# Queries about transferring money from India to USA when immigrating

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, transfer, immigration

We are immigrating to the USA in a few months. I need to transfer the sales proceeds of my Indian property to the USA, some months after immigrating.

I also have a healthy mutual fund portfolio, in India, that I intent to maintain as is. I plan to transfer it's dividends and / or sales proceeds to the USA as and when I need.

I have a few queries.

1. How much money can be transferred from India into the USA? (The money that I intend to transfer is going to be tax paid, legal, bank balance in India.)
2. As a green holder residing and filing tax returns in the USA, what kind of tax implications can I expect in the USA, on such transfers?